# How reorder parallel builds in chain

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

We are using TeamCity 9 and we have defined build configuration looks like:

```
          --> unit tests ---------|
          ^                       ˇ
compile ->+-> integration tests ->+--> deploy
          ˇ                       ^
          --> acceptance tests ---|
```

Dependencies between build are defined as *Snapshot dependency* ([documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Build+Dependencies+Setup])). All tests builds are running in parallel, but I need to define order because  `integration test` needs more time than others so it'll be good to run this test build first.

It's possible to define order or priorities for each build in chain?

Comment: Do these really compete against each other? I'd think that each runs on a different agent (set of agents), isn't that the case?

Comment: You have right, my example was bad. I have a pool of agents and my goal is define order of parallel builds, e.g. `integration tests` execute first, `acceptance tests` second and `unit tests` as last. Each build can run on all agents - agents have same configuration.

Comment: @Rudis , I have this same question, did you ever find a way to do this?

Comment: How about [build priorities](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/working-with-build-queue.html#Managing+Build+Priorities)?

Answer (score 0):

Order of builds (waiting mechanism) can be managed by using the build feature named shared resources.

See page @ Jetbrains :::
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Shared+Resources

Comment: Thanks, but I want to execute all my test builds in parallel but in defined order. I read your article but I still don't know how the shared resources can help me.